# Сверстала макет, но он оказался меньше экрана. Как можно исправить?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Сверстала свой первый макет, наложила плагин, чтобы сверить расположение объектов после верстки и сам макет,но макет оказался меньше моего экрана ноутбука и сверстанный сайт теперь больше макета, хотя я все переносила по пискелям. 
Это исправляется через настройки адаптивности @media в css и можно не переживать, если в будущем попадется такой макет?

Answer (score 0):

```
body 
  max-width: ширина макета;
  width: 100%;
```